# Istio-Gateway does not obtain an external IP with EKS v2

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

We try to deploy the hello world application from istio (booking info).

## Environment

Region: Ireland
Service: EKS v2
Istio: 1.0.1
Helm:

```
  Client: Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
  Server: Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

## Context

We have intalled istio 1.0.1 with helm, with this command:

```
helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set sidecarInjectorWebhook.enabled=true --set galley.enabled=true
```

We tried also to install istio without galley and without auto sidecar injection without success. Our ingress controller does not obtain an IP.

But unfortunately, our istio-ingressgateway has no external-ip. The status PENDING means that the platform (here AWS) can't create a LoadBalancer.
It can't be the case, because we were also successfull doing that, when we were in region Oregon with EKS v1. The LoadBalancer was created.

```
kubectl get services -n istio-system -o wide

NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) SELECTOR
istio-ingressgateway       LoadBalancer   172.20.195.15    <pending>     80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31020/TCP,8060:30312/TCP,853:31767/TCP15030:32216/TCP,15031:32384/TCP   17h app=istio-ingressgateway,istio=ingressgateway
```

Answer (score 3):

A public subnet in EKS is needed for the loadbalancer.
After adding a public subnet, everthing works fine.

Comment: I have added public subnet , still showing pending. I am being with this for 2 days! Also i have added the tag "kubernetes.io/role/elb" with value "1". Still no luck so far!

Comment: Am facing the same issue. Any solution?